# Allow review for a Change only from authors that are added explicitly

Tags: git, gerrit

In gerrit, you can add particular people as reviewers for a Change in the web interface using the "Add reviewers to this change" button.

Is it possible to allow review **only** from people who are added explicitly as reviewers using this method?

Comment: By `added explicitly as reviewers` do you mean `%r=<REVIEWERS_LIST>` syntax when doing `git push`?

Comment: It really depends on how the access rights are set up for your project (and all the parent projects). Generally, if someone can find your review with a search, they can add themselves as a reviewer (or simply read the code invisibly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. I thought it might help to create a custom [Prolog Rule](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/prolog-cookbook.html) like the one for [excluding the author](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/prolog-cookbook.html#NonAuthorCodeReview) but unfortunately [Prolog Facts](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/prolog-change-facts.html) don't include information about assigned code reviewers. I don't see a different way to approach this.